# Does vim have something to handle this delete case?

Tags: vim

Imagine I have this text:

```
select_id + " option:selected"))).val();
```

And my cursor is after `+`. What kind of motion would allow me to delete everything until the last `)`, without including it in the deletion. So, after deletion, I would like to have this text:

```
select_id).val();
```

What if I have any number of `)` before `.val()`? Something like `)))))))))))){N more}).val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `vt.ld` This turn on visual mode, move cursor to dot, then go one character back and delete selection.

Answer (score 4):

If your cursor is before `+`, just type `dt.`

Comment: Won't `dt` also delete the `)` as well ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like `d/)\.` should do it but you would have to be before the +.

The d command can be modified using lots of different things, e.g., dW delete to space, dw delete next word, D delete to end of line, dd delete line, etc.

Comment: Add b. "bd/)\." without quotes.

Comment: so like I said, you would have to be before the +